# change an ascending sort to descending

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following code to sort a list but I need to make it a descending sort,

```
List list = new LinkedList(thismap.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
                .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
    }
});

Map output = new LinkedHashMap();
for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    output.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Just flip the arguments in `compare`, the rest of the code can remain identical.

Answer (score 8):

A common, general purpose technique is to wrap a Comparator in a reverse Comparator by simply swapping the arguments.

```
class ReverseComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final Comparator target;

    public ReverseComparator(Comparator<T> target) {
        super();
        this.target = target;
    }

    public int compare(T first, T second) {
        return target.compare(second, first);
    } 
}
```

To use it with our example:

```
Comparator original = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
            .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, new ReverseComparator(original));
```

Comment: Why not just use `java.util.Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator)` instead of rolling your own `ReverseComparator` class?

Comment: @StephenC  Thanks for catching the edge condition with -1.  It has been removed from my response.

Answer (score 6):

The simple general answer is to use `java.util.Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator)`.

```
Comparator myComparator = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
        .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
    }
}
// ... or whatever.

Comparator myReverseComparator = Collections.reverseOrder(myComparator);
```

Alternatively, a specific solution would be to flip the parameters in the compare method:

```
Comparator myReverseComparator = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o2, Object o1) {  // <== NOTE - params reversed!!
    return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
        .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
    }
}
```

---

Note that multiplying by `-1` is an **incorrect** solution because of the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` edge case.  `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1` is ... `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

It's all about changing the content of the method below:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
{
    return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
           .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
}
```

Return a different result than the value of the statement below:

```
((Comparable)((Map.Entry)(o2)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry)(o1)).getValue());
```

Let's say the statement above is assigned to x. Then you should return 1 if x < 0, 
  return -1 if x > 0 and return 0 if x == 0, just inside the `compare()` method.

So your method could look like this:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
{
   int x = ((Comparable)((Map.Entry)(o2)).getValue())
             .compareTo(((Map.Entry)(o1)).getValue());
   if(x > 0)
     return -1;
   else if (x < 0)
     return 1;

   return 0;
}
```